# Insert strings from data table to gridview and show them as links

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a database field with strings that are actually links, lets say I have there "www.google.com" saved as nvchar, now I want to fill a grid view from data table, and show each string as a link.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to code something so far?

Answer (score 0):

You looking for  [**HyperLinkField**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) in gridview

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false">
        <Columns>
             <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="Name"
            datanavigateurlfields="Url"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="{0}"          
            headertext="Url"
            target="_blank" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The problem is that it ads the "local host" link before the actual link, and it tries to go to "http://localhost:xxxxx/www.google.com" ,how to remove the localhost?

Comment: Can you update question with aspx page markup for gridview and sample data of url in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast these cells as **HyperLinkFields** on **RowDataBound** event of your **GridView**.

Try this:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    HyperLink link = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as HyperLink;
    if (link != null)
    {
      link.NavigateUrl = link.Text; //"Link Url";
      link.Text = "Click to open this link"; // You may alter the link text.
    }
  }
}
```